# Matlab: Matrix manipulation: Change values of pixels around center pixel in binary matrix

Tags: matlab

I have another problem today:
I have a binary matrix t, in which 1 represents a river channel, 0 represents flood plane and surrounding mountains:

```
t = Alog>10;
figure
imshow(t)
axis xy
```

For further calculations, I would like to expand the area of the riverchannel a few pixels in each direction. Generally speaking, I want to have a wider channel displayed in the image, to include a larger region in a later hydraulic model.

Here is my attempt, which does work in certain regions, but in areas where the river runs diagonal to the x-y axis, it does not widen the channel. There seems to be a flow in approaching this, which I cannot quite grasp.

```
[q,o] = find(t == 1);   

qq = zeros(length(q),11);
oo = zeros(length(o),11);

% add +-5 pixel to result
for z=1:length(q)
    qq(z,:) = q(z)-5:1:q(z)+5;
    oo(z,:) = o(z)-5:1:o(z)+5;
end
% create column vectors
qq = qq(:);
oo = oo(:);

cords = [oo qq]; % [x y]

% remove duplicates
cords = unique(cords,'rows');

% get limits of image
[limy limx] = size(t);

% restrict to x-limits
cords = cords(cords(:,1)>=1,:);
cords = cords(cords(:,1)<=limx,:);

% restrict to y-limits
cords = cords(cords(:,2)>=1,:);
cords = cords(cords(:,2)<=limy,:);

% test image
l = zeros(size(img));
l(sub2ind(size(l), cords(:,2)',cords(:,1)')) = 1;
figure
imshow(l)
axis xy
```

This is the image I get:

It does widen the channel in some areas, but generally there seems to be a flaw with my approach. When I use the same approach on a diagonal line of pixels, it will not widen the line at all, because it will just create more pairs of [1 1; 2 2; 3 3; etc].
Is there a better approach to this or even something from the realm of image processing? 
A blur filter with a set diameter should be working somewhat similar, but I could not find anything helpful...

PS: I wasn't allowed to add the images, although I already have 10 rep, so here are the direct links:

http://imageshack.us/a/img14/3122/channelthin.jpg
http://imageshack.us/a/img819/1787/channelthick.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the image processing toolbox, you should use the [imdilate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) function. This performs the morphological [dilation operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_%28morphology%29). Try the following code:

```
SE = strel('square',3);
channelThick = imdilate(channelThin,SE);
```

where SE is a 3x3 square [structuring element](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html) used to dilate the image stored in channelThin. This will expand the regions in channelThin by one pixel in every direction. To expand more, use a larger structuring element, or multiple iterations.

Comment: Perfect, the quick and easy solution I was looking for. I wonder if there is a way of finding solutions like this (without having used them before) without asking communities like this. I just cannot make the connection from my problems to such tools...

Answer (score 1):

You may apply [morphological operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology) from image processing. [Morphological dilation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) can be used in your example.

From the image processing toolbox, you can use [bwmorth](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) command `BW2 = bwmorph(BW,'dilate')` or  imdilate command `IM2 = imdilate(IM,SE)`.

Where `IM` is your image and `SE` is the structuring element. You can set `SE = ones(3);` to dilate the binary image by "one pixel" - but it can be changed depending on your application. Or you can dilate the image several times with the same structuring element if needed.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you! Is there any different between the usage of imdilate and bwmorph, except for the fact that bwmorph does not allow changes to the structure element?

Comment: There is no difference for binary input image. In general, the functions in the Image Processing Toolbox that start
with "bw" refer to operations on BINARY images, while those with "im"
prefixes refer to functions that operate on GRAYSCALE images. I think `imdilate` can take a grayscale image as input and it lets you set your own structure element.

Comment: I see, alright! Thanks for your equally useful answer and help!